# Can't find how SolidWorks master file generate design accroading to choosen items

Tags: autocad, cad, solidworks, solidworksapi, solidworkspdmapi

I'm new to SolidWorks, and facing a problem from last 4 days, here is the details of my problem which i'm facing.

I have a folder containing two .SLDASM and a lot of .SLDPRT files, I know that .SLDASM are master file and .SLDPRT are part file.

is there any formula can be written, which will generate the design accroading to my selected options?

like my master file is HS35X.SLDASM i know it is a master file of HS35X model, a website is using this file and generating image accroading to selected option.
Website Link : https://www.3dcontentcentral.com/Model-Preview-Resp.aspx?catalogid=1139&id=1750921&partnumber=HS35A41CAU0XA000

like if i select this options from dropdown
PPR: 2048
Input/Output Voltage: 5-28v In/Out (7272)
Bore Size/Options: 5/8" bore via insert
Connector Style: 10 pin MS style w/o Plug, Avtron/BEI Pinout

it is generating the image automatically from that master file. so i want to know where in the master file this selection configuration is written or is it written at all in master file? or it is generating image or fetching image from somewhere else?, and how to see that configuration if it is really written in master file?

I have installed the SolidWorks2022 software and have looked through almost all the options, but since I am new to SolidWorks2022 I can't find anything.

Comment: This question is too broad. Are you asking for this encoder in particular or any Solidworks files? What are you trying to do? You won't find any drop-down that you see on the website in any of those Solidworks Files. If you want to change a set of dimensions on this encoder, you will have to manually set the values of each of the dimensions. But Solidworks models can be designed differently. A different Solidworks model could have configurations that you can select to get what you want, but not this particular model of encoder